# REGEXP_COUNT equivalent in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

Is there an equivalent function in Spark SQL that does what [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_COUNT.html) do as in redshift?

Basically I'm trying to count the number of substrings.

```
REGEXP('1->2->3->456', '->')
```

should return 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp_count is available in Spark 3.4.0, so you can try upgrading your spark version.

Ref doc - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/sql/#regexp_count